# How do I locate minima in an array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a code to plot a heatmap for a set of data, represented as `(x, y, f(x, y))`, and I want to find the local minimum points.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

data = np.genfromtxt('data.dat',
                     skip_header=1,
                     delimiter='        ')


x, y, z = data[:, 1], data[::, 0], data[:, 2]
x, y, z = x*180/math.pi, y*180/math.pi, z - min(z)

xi, yi = np.linspace(max(x), min(x), 1000), np.linspace(max(y), min(y), 1000)

xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)


zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='linear')


plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, shading='auto', cmap='jet')

plt.colorbar(label='Heatmap')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()


plt.show()
```

Here's code to generate some fake data:

```
import math

with open('data.dat', 'w') as arquivo:

    for x in range(20):
        for y in range(20):
            z = -math.exp(math.sin(x*y)- math.cos(y))
            arquivo.write(f"{x}\t\t{y}\t\t{z}\n")
```

Heatmap example with minimum points circled:

[image]

I tried to use `np.gradient`, thinking that maybe by taking two derivatives I would be able to determine the local minimum points (zero in the first derivative and negative in the second), but I was not able to make any of it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find local minima, we usually used some gradient based optimizations like gradient descent. However, it is not easy to find all local minima unless doing a lot of "restart" (generally people are happy with one local minimum). One straightforward method to your problem is using grid search: if the current point is less than the neighbor around it, it is one local minimum. The code snippet is below

```py
# Function to get the neighbors of a given point (i,j)
def get_neighbors(i, j, shape):
    neighbors = []

    for x in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for y in [-1, 0, 1]:
            ni, nj = i + x, j + y

            if (0 <= ni < shape[0]) and (0 <= nj < shape[1]) and (x, y) != (0, 0):
                neighbors.append((ni, nj))

    return neighbors

local_minima = []

# Iterate over the 2D grid
for i in range(zi.shape[0]):
    for j in range(zi.shape[1]):
        current_value = zi[i, j]
        neighbors = get_neighbors(i, j, zi.shape)

        # Check if the current point is less than all its neighbors
        if all(current_value < zi[n[0], n[1]] for n in neighbors):
            local_minima.append((xi[i, j], yi[i, j], current_value))
# Print the local minima
for loc in local_minima:
    print(f"Local minimum value {loc[2]} at location ({loc[0]}, {loc[1]}).")
```

And then plot the local minima

```py
# Marking all the local minima on the plot
for loc in local_minima:
    plt.scatter(loc[0], loc[1], color='red', s=100, marker='x')
```

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score -1):

There's a few ways to do this, but the way I would do it is to create a model of the map background using a [scipy filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters) like the [uniform filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.fourier_uniform.html#scipy.ndimage.fourier_uniform), with a size big enough to encompass several major features on the map (say half the image size). Then create another model of the standard deviation of the map using the [standard deviation filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.standard_deviation.html#scipy.ndimage.standard_deviation).

Local minima occur where `(original_map - background) / standard_deviation < threshold_value`.

You can play around with the `threshold_value` (maybe negative 2-3 would do), and the size of the filtering windows.

The python code is left as an exercise. :)

Comment: **The python code is left as an exercise. :)** isn't really an answer, since the OP is asking for a coding answer - Please review [answer]

Comment: It felt more like a methodology question rather than a coding question. The OP didn't ask "how can I implement gradient search", but "how can I find local minima". Fair call though.